# Problems running pyinstaller on Windows for first time

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to run pyinstaller on a Windows 10 machine and I am getting the error below. Could somebody tell me that is the problem? I cannot understand which file is not finding.

Python is version 3.10.5 and pyinstaller is version 5.1.

Error here:

C:\Users\username\Desktop\CROWGUI>pyinstaller --onefile --noconfirm --console --clean --log-level=WARN --key=MySuperSecretPassword --strip --add-data=“commander.py;.” crow_gui.py
5983 WARNING: Ignoring /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit imported from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py - only basenames are supported with ctypes imports!
5983 WARNING: Ignoring /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation imported from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py - only basenames are supported with ctypes imports!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py”, line 196, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py”, line 86, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py”, line 7, in 
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py”, line 178, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py”, line 59, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py”, line 842, in main
build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py”, line 764, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File “C:\Users\username\Desktop\CROWGUI\crow_gui.spec”, line 24, in 
exe = EXE(
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py”, line 506, in **init**
self.pkg = PKG(
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py”, line 206, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py”, line 173, in **postinit**
self.assemble()
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py”, line 269, in assemble
fnm = checkCache(
File “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py”, line 367, in checkCache
subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py”, line 501, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py”, line 969, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py”, line 1438, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and format your error code properly

Comment: Having the exact same error message... :'(

Answer (score 2):

After trying installing several versions of PyInstaller and looking into the  official script of PyInstaller, I found out that the issue is related to the --strip option. After removing that option all worked find.

Comment: Right on!  That worked.  It's hard to tell which state of the button means Enable, so probably will trip others up.  To be clear I have both strip and no upx highlighted grey (Pressed) so that they're not blue appearing in auto-py-to-exe.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to judge just by the log. Where are your files located? Which file is your main file and which ones do you need to be included? What is your folder structure?